# Checking whether a number is in Fibonacci Sequence?

Tags: java, algorithm

It was asked to find a way to check whether a number is in the Fibonacci Sequence or not.
The constraints are
1≤T≤10^5

1≤N≤10^10

where the T is the number of test cases,

and N is the given number, the Fibonacci candidate to be tested.

I wrote it the following using the fact a number is Fibonacci if and only if one or both of (5*n2 + 4) or (5*n2 – 4) is a perfect square :-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
        int cand = sc.nextInt();
        if(cand < 0){System.out.println("IsNotFibo"); return; }
        int aTest =(5 * (cand *cand)) + 4;
        int bTest = (5 * (cand *cand)) - 4;
        int sqrt1 = (int)Math.sqrt(aTest);// Taking square root of aTest, taking into account only the integer part.
        int sqrt2 = (int)Math.sqrt(bTest);// Taking square root of bTest, taking into account only the integer part.
        if((sqrt1 * sqrt1 == aTest)||(sqrt2 * sqrt2 == bTest)){
            System.out.println("IsFibo");
        }else{
            System.out.println("IsNotFibo");
        }
       }
     }
  }
```

But its not clearing all the test cases? What bug fixes I can do ?

Comment: Should I delete it from here?

Comment: Muse about the numbers representable by java types, the specified input ranges and the ranges of the intermediate results of the test in your question.

Comment: No you shouldn't.  The codereview site is NOT for asking about how to fix bugs.  If you are not "clearing" the testcases, you have bugs to fix, not "improvements" to make.

Comment: When I cut an paste your code, there is a missing } at the end. Your really should be more careful about formatting--it is one of the simplest ways to prevent errors and wasting time.

Comment: Another thought: is `T` part of the specified input, and does your program properly process it?

Comment: Yes it correctly processes that, this program cleared 5 test cases but failed to clear the last 4 test cases.
@ Phil Freihofner point noted.Will be more careful in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests for perfect squares involve floating point calculations.  That is liable to give you incorrect answers because floating point calculations typically give you inaccurate results.  (Floating point is at best an approximate to Real numbers.)

In this case `sqrt(n*n)` might give you `n - epsilon` for some small epsilon and `(int) sqrt(n*n)` would then be `n - 1` instead of the expected `n`.

Restructure your code so that the tests are performed using integer arithmetic.  But note that N < 10<sup>10</sup> means that N<sup>2</sup> < 10<sup>20</sup>.  That is bigger than a `long` ... so you will need to use ...

**UPDATE**

There is more to it than this.  First, `Math.sqrt(double)` is guaranteed to give you a `double` result that is rounded to the closest `double` value to the true square root.  So you might think we are in the clear (as it were).

But the problem is that N  multiplied by N has up to 20 significant digits ... which is more than can be represented when you widen the number to a `double` in order to make the `sqrt` call.  (A `double` has 15.95 decimal digits of precision, according to Wikipedia.)

On top of that, the code as written does this:

```
int cand = sc.nextInt();
int aTest = (5 * (cand * cand)) + 4;
```

For large values of `cand`, that is liable to overflow.  And it will even overflow if you use `long` instead of `int` ... given that the `cand` values may be up to 10^10.  (A `long` can represent numbers up to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807 ... which is less than 10<sup>20</sup>.)  And then we have to multiply N<sup>2</sup> by 5.

In summary, while the code should work for small candidates, for really large ones it could either break when you attempt to read the candidate (as an `int`) or it could give the wrong answer due to integer overflow (as a `long`).

Fixing this requires a significant rethink.  (Or deeper analysis than I have done to show that the computational hazards don't result in an incorrect answer *for any large N in the range of possible inputs*.)

Comment: The only equality tests I see are between integers.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner - but those integers are casted from floating points.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner - you are right.  However fp is still the problem.  I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A much simpler solution is based on the fact that [there are only 49 Fibonacci numbers below 10^10](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html).

Precompute them and store them in an array or hash table for existency checks.

The runtime complexity will be O(log N + T):

```
Set<Long> nums = new HashSet<>();
long a = 1, b = 2;
while (a <= 10000000000L) {
    nums.add(a);
    long c = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = c;
}
// then for each query, use nums.contains() to check for Fibonacci-ness
```

If you want to go down the perfect square route, you might want to use arbitrary-precision arithmetics:

```
// find ceil(sqrt(n)) in O(log n) steps
BigInteger ceilSqrt(BigInteger n) {
    // use binary search to find smallest x with x^2 >= n
    BigInteger lo = BigInteger.valueOf(1),
               hi = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    while (lo.compareTo(hi) < 0) {
        BigInteger mid = lo.add(hi).divide(2);
        if (mid.multiply(mid).compareTo(x) >= 0)
            hi = mid;
        else
            lo = mid.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    return lo;
}
// checks if n is a perfect square
boolean isPerfectSquare(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger x = ceilSqrt(n);
    return x.multiply(x).equals(n);
}
```

Comment: How about `Set<Number> nums = new HashSet<Long>(49);`?

Comment: @greybeard What about it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-number-fibonacci-number/) link **a number is Fibonacci if and only if one or both of (5*n2 + 4) or (5*n2 – 4) is a perfect square** so you can basically do this check.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The OP seems to have done this already now. The check is not easy to do under the given constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) and the [Fibonacci Q-matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciQ-Matrix.html) for a `O((log n)^2)` solution per test case if you use [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Your solution does not work because it involves rounding floating point square roots of large numbers (potentially large enough not to even fit in a `long`), which sometimes will not be exact.

The binary search will work like this: find `Q^m`: if the `m`-th Fibonacci number is larger than yours, set `right = m`, if it is equal return `true`, else set `left = m + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

As it was correctly said, sqrt could be rounded down. So:

- Even if you use long instead of int, it has 18 digits.
- even if you use Math.round(), not simply (int) or (long). Notice, your function wouldn't work correctly even on small numbers because of that.

double have 14 digits, long has 18, so you can't work with squares, you need 20 digits.

BigInteger and BigDecimal have no sqrt() function.

So, you have three ways:

- write your own sqrt for BigInteger.
- check all numbers around the found unprecise double sqrt() for being a real sqrt. That means also working with numbers and their errors simultaneously. (it's horror!)
- count all Fibonacci numbers under 10^10 and compare against them.

The last variant is by far the simplest one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like to me the for-loop doesn't make any sense ?

When you remove the for-loop for me the program works as advertised:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Solution {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cand = sc.nextInt();

            if(cand < 0){System.out.println("IsNotFibo"); return; }
            int aTest = 5 * cand *cand + 4;
            int bTest = 5 * cand *cand - 4;
            int sqrt1 =  (int)Math.sqrt(aTest);
            int sqrt2 = (int)Math.sqrt(bTest);
            if((sqrt1 * sqrt1 == aTest)||(sqrt2 * sqrt2 == bTest)){
                System.out.println("IsFibo");
            }else{
                System.out.println("IsNotFibo");
            }


    }

}
```

Comment: What does it mean for a number to be a `perfect square`? What might `number of test cases` refer to?

Comment: Yeah. x = sqrt(a) implies x^2 = a, so that test is meaningless. A perfect square test should be 'is x an integer?', I guess

Comment: It won't work as advertised for large enough values of `cand`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to test for a given candidate, yes? What is the for loop accomplishing? Could the results of the loop be throwing your testing program off?

Also, there is a missing } in the code. It will not run as posted without adding another } at the end, after which it runs fine for the following input:

```
10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
IsFibo
IsFibo
IsFibo
IsNotFibo
IsFibo
IsNotFibo
IsNotFibo
IsFibo
IsNotFibo
IsNotFibo
```

Comment: n number of test cases are lined up in each test cases. first line in the input tells me the number of test cases and I run the loop n times to perform the test on each number in that test case. I hope I am making myself clear.

Comment: Are you getting false positives? false negatives? What numbers aren't clearing?

Comment: Yes the T is the number of cases, and based on that I get series of N's on which I do the test. Yes you are correct.

Comment: I was confused by your dual use of N, first as a spec for a test case number, then as a count for the number of items to be tested. Again, keeping these things fastidiously consistent goes a long way to reducing debug time!

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account all the above suggestions I wrote the following which passed all test cases

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    long[] fib = new long[52];
    Set<Long> fibSet = new HashSet<>(52);
    fib[0] = 0L;
    fib[1] = 1L;
    for(int i = 2; i < 52; i++){
        fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i - 2];
        fibSet.add(fib[i]);
    }

    int n = sc.nextInt();
    long cand;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cand = sc.nextLong();
        if(cand < 0){System.out.println("IsNotFibo");continue;}
        if(fibSet.contains(cand)){
            System.out.println("IsFibo");
        }else{
            System.out.println("IsNotFibo");
        }  
     }
   }
 }
```

I wanted to be on the safer side hence I choose 52 as the number of elements in the Fibonacci sequence under consideration.